# My Ubuntu Server Ports got locked

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I just tried to join to my Jenkins on my VPS as usual. When I try to access the URL it returns the error code ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. This happens as well with port 8080 for my website and other ports. I can join to my SSH session.

The ports are allowed by the UFW.

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
21                         ALLOW       Anywhere
9080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
27015/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
7777/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
7778/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
27020/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
7778/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
27050/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
27050/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
27015/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
27000/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
27100/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
27036/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
27100/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
27031/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
4379/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
4380/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
27014/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
27030/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
27016                      ALLOW       Anywhere
27020                      ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
9080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27015/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
7777/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
7778/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27020/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
7778/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27050/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27050/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27015/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27000/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27100/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27036/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27100/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27031/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
4379/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
4380/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27014/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27030/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27016 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27020 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: Check the Jenkins logfile. Delete or move the Jenkins logfile and restart Jenkins... until you see a helpful error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I had a series of restrictions in iptables that prevented incoming connections except for SSH.

To disable these restrictions I ran the following commands:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F
```

After that, I activated ufw and added the ports configured in my jenkins (9080).

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow 9080
```

I found the answer on this post: [How to start stop iptables on ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/129086/how-to-start-stop-iptables-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Great that it worked! 